# Magento 2: wrong shipping method saved in order

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, magento2

We have 2 delivery methods enabled on Magento 2.4.6: home delivery and a custom store pickup.
If the home delivery method is selected and correctly saved in the order, the customer's address is entered as the delivery and billing address.
With the store pickup method, the store address is filled in.
But with some orders, the shipping and the billing addresses are the customer's but the shipping method saved is store pickup with null as pickup location ID. Those orders were delivered to the customers' home addresses.
So they should be home delivery orders, but they are being created as store pickup.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this issue?

Fano

We expect the home delivery method to be correctly saved in the order if it's selected, instead of store pickup with the customers' address.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.